# How do I get an item id from an action bar popup menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu, popupmenu

I am having trouble accessing an item within a popup menu once I press a `MenuItem` from the action bar. In other words, I do not know how to get the id of the items from the popup menu once I press on the action bar item.
Note: The `public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)` does not work.

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle presses on the action bar items

        if(item.getItemId()== R.id.action_settings) {
            openPopup();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        public void openPopup() {
            //find the settings button first
            View ActionItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_settings); 
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, ActionItemView); 
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup);
            popupMenu.show();


       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)        {

            switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                case R.id.action_search:
                    openSearch();

                case R.id.PopupSettings:
                    openSettings();
                }   

       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to implement the `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` interface first, then implements the method defined in that interface which is `onMenuItemClick()` method, if you decide to use an anonymous class, you can do it directly in the `onCreate()` method as well like this, this way, you don't have to use the `implements` keyword at all.

```
popMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true; //return true to indicate it was handled, false otherwise

            case R.id.PopupSettings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }   
    });
```

You have to use `setOnMenuItemClickListener()` to set a callback method on that menu every time the user selects an option, or your popup will not do anything at all. Basically, it is a must to implement the `setOnMenuClickListener()` method to listen to the event for a popup menu.